# How to declare an instance variable in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, oop

I am looking to do something like this:

```
@interface Player : NSObject

    @properties int hitPoints = 200,
                    mana      = 100;

@end
```

So that every time I initiate an object of class Player, that object will have
those variables with those specific values.

Do I need to declare this in the @implementation section?

I know that i can set those variables in the init faction
but i wonder if there is another way.

I am new to Objective C, and OOP in general.

Comment: If you want to give a property a non-default initial value you have to do it in init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your properties to be public you would want to declare them in your header file and then, as you said, in the init method of your implementation file you could give them their default values.